# HTML5/CSS User location select

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

You know those nice dropdown menus for chosing your location, those in which you type something and it start narrowing it down to various location/countreis/languages.

I refuse to believe that everyone implements them by hand but I'm having a hard time finding some examples/templates to start implementing one.

Do you guys have any idea how they are called or if there is a special html element that implements them ?

Comment: I read that in Joey(Friend's) Voice !

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Try searching for "custom select" or "custom dropdown"...and yes, they are coded by hand.

Comment: There are many auto-complete plugins and tools available.  And implementing a custom one isn't terribly difficult.  Though it's not really clear if that's what you're actually asking.  It also sounds like you're asking how to build the Google Maps search bar, which would simply be far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you use an API for that. Here's an exmaple, based on most reliable (Google Api)

```
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
          id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use an HTML Datalist Element.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

```html
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

jQuery UI is available if you want to get fancy.

See: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/